# Can two light fixture switches share a neutral?

Tags: wiring, switch, neutral

I have two porch lanterns ( sgl pole sw #1) and one foyer ceiling light (slg pole sw #2) in an existing two gang box, but I'm not sure how to use some existing old black pipes for my new wiring.

One porch fixture has a direct pipe from the box, so it easily gets its own black and white. But the other porch light (which I want to switch together with the first)...its pipe is branched off the foyer light's electrical box.  Can my second porch light share the foyer light's neutral, or should I bring it its own neutral ? I do already have the second light's hot coming through the foyer box.

Comment: Where is the second porch light's hot wire coming from?

Answer (score 3):

If they are all on the same circuit, yes.

If not, no.

If one circuit breaker turns off all three lights, then they are on the same circuit and you should be good to go.

Comment: I agree if 1 circuit breaker turns all the lights off you can share the neutral.+

Comment: But you do need to make sure that *all conductors of the same circuit ... shall be contained within the same raceway, ... cable* NEC 300.3(B).

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it to work on one neutral okay, as most of my trouble was that as I worked on my junction box, an old wire at a prior box had come loose and was making intermittent connection !! Previous owner had buried a box and I only found it after too long. Ninety yr old houses are like puzzles with a few missing pieces.

Comment: Is "raceway" in this case defined as the outer cable sheathing?

Comment: No, it's the conduit (described in the question as "old black pipe")

Comment: @isherwood I believe the code specifically says "*within the same raceway,... cable,...*".